# Remove item from array in Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following task list app. I am trying to implement a `delete` function. I get I need to use `splice` to remove the item from the `array` but how do I target only the item whose button I clicked on?

https://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/txtrage5/1/

**JS**

```
new Vue({

    el: '#tasks',

    data: {
        message: 'Tasks',
        completed: null,
        newTaskName: '',
        tasklist: [
            { description: 'Read', completed: true },
            { description: 'Write', completed: true },
            { description: 'Edit', completed: false },
            { description: 'Publish', completed: false }
        ]
    },

    methods: {
        completeTask: function(task){
            // console.log(this.tasks.description);
            task.completed = true;
        },
        newTask: function(){
            this.tasklist.push({description: this.newTaskName, completed: false});
        },
        removeTask: function(task){
            this.tasklist.splice(this.task.index, 1);
        }
    }

})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="tasks">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            {{ message }}
        </h3>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix" v-for="task in tasklist" >
            {{ task.description }}
            <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" v-if="!task.completed" @click="completeTask(task)">Complete</button> -->
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm pull-right" role="group" v-if="!task.completed">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="completeTask(task)">Complete</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="removeTask(task)">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm completed text-muted pull-right disabled" v-else>Completed</button>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
            <input v-model="newTaskName" @keyup.enter="newTask" type="text" class="pull-left">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" @click="newTask">Add Task</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
removeTask: function(task){
    this.tasklist.splice(this.tasklist.indexOf(task), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the index of the task in the `v-for` to decide which item to `splice()`:

```
v-for="(task, index) in tasklist"
```

Your button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="removeTask(index)">Delete</button>
```

And then simply:

```
removeTask: function(index) {
    this.tasklist.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Vue2 use `delete`. [See API.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete)

```
removeTask: function(index){
    this.$delete(this.tasklist, index)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf to get the current index from the array

```
remove: function (task){
      this.tasklist.splice(this.tasklist.indexOf(task),1);
    },
```